# Java: Get maximum value of variables

Tags: java, max

I am trying to find the largest values of these three variables (aCounter, bCounter, cCounter) that has been calculated. Java does not like how I am putting them into the string. 
Thanks in advance guys!

```
   double aCounter=0;
   double bCounter=0;
   double cCounter=0;

         { code to count occurrences of each character in text file }

   String lines = aCounter + bCounter + cCounter;
    String [] array = lines.split (" "); //splits with a space
    int largestInt = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (String numberString : array )
    {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
        if (number > largestInt)
        {
            largestInt = number;
        }
    }
bw.write ( largestInt );
```

Answer (score 4):

It's strange what you're doing:

- Concatenate three numbers into a string
- Split the string
- Parse numbers out of the split result
- Find the max....

You could find the max value directly from the numbers:

```
int largestInt = Math.max(aCounter, Math.max(bCounter, cCounter));
```

Or if you don't want to use `Math.max`, then:

```
double largestOfAB = aCounter > bCounter ? aCounter : bCounter;
int largestInt = largestOfAB > cCounter ? largestOfAB : cCounter;
```

Or if you want a loop solution:

```
double largest = aCounter;
for (double number : new double[]{ bCounter, cCounter})
{
    if (number > largestInt)
    {
        largest = number;
    }
}
int largestInt = (int) double;
```

Btw it begs the question, why are `aCounter`, `bCounter` and `cCounter` of type `double`?
The count of letters suggests integer numbers.
Unless it's average counts. But then if it's average counts then why would you want an `int` valued `largestInt` at the end?
Since the type of `largestInt` is `int`, it would make sense to use `int` instead for the counters.

Comment: It is double because I have divided the count by the total number of letters.

Comment: I see. In that case, I changed the type of largestOfAB to double in my post

Answer (score 0):

```
String lines = aCounter +" "+ bCounter +" "+ cCounter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
String lines = aCounter + bCounter + cCounter;
```

to

```
String lines = aCounter + " " + bCounter + " " + cCounter;
```

If you REALLY want to use this way, otherwise

```
int largest=0;
if(aCounter>bCounter) {
 if(aCounter>cCounter) {
  largest=aCounter;
 } else {
  largest=cCounter;
 }
} else {
 if(bCounter>cCounter) {
  largest=bCounter;
 } else {
  largest=cCounter;
 }
}
```

or

```
int largest=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
if(aCounter>largest) largest=aCounter;
if(bCounter>largest) largest=bCounter;
if(cCounter>largest) largest=cCounter;
```

would be a better way, skipping the use of Strings.